# For which values of x the following series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series: $x+x^{1+\frac{1}{2}}+x^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$
By ratio test, 
$\lim_{n \to \infty }x^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \lt 1$
How should I conclude from this?

Also, for any c>0, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}c^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.
So does this mean that this series won't converge for any positive real number?

Comment: For which values of $x$ is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty }x^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \lt 1$?

Comment: As an experiment, using a calculator, find the value of $ (0.5)^{0.01}$.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be so much an explanation so much as different links that all together equal a final answer.

First, we may rewrite your sum as

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{H_n}$$

where $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$ (the Harmonic numbers). From the definition of the Harmonic numbers (taken from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) page), we know $H_n=\psi(n+1)+\gamma$ where $\psi(x)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant (approximately $0.58$). Then $f(x)$ may be rewritten as

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{H_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\psi(n+1)+\gamma}.$$

We can input this in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28x%5E%28digamma%28n%2B1%29%2B%28euler-mascheroni%20constant%29%29%2Cn%2C1%2Cinfty%29) which outputs that the series converges when $\log(|x|)<-1$. Solving this, we find that the domain of $f(x)$ is all complex numbers whose magnitude is less than $e^{-1}$. If you restrict the series to real inputs and outputs only, then the domain is $x\in[0,e^{-1})$.

Comment: I have not studied Digamma function yet. Is there any other way ?Thanks .

Comment: Speaking loosely, you could say that $H_n\sim\log(n)$ and then arrive at the same result. There might be more difficulties with hammering down the details though

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{k}
=\ln(n)+c_n
$
where
$|c_n| < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^m x^{\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m x^{\ln(n)+c_n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m e^{\ln(x)\ln(n)+c_n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m n^{\ln(x)}e^{c_n}\\
&=b_n\sum_{n=1}^m n^{\ln(x)}
\qquad e^{-1} < b_n < e\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum converges for
$\ln(x) < -1
(x < 1/e)$
and diverges for
$\ln(x) \ge -1
(x \ge 1/e)
$.